# problems with bash script array aways giving same error

Tags: bash

i am having a bit of an issue with the below bash script that it always has the error 
./check2.sh: 2: Syntax error: "(" unexpected ,    i have tried every which way to try and fix this i am probably missing something simple.    can anyone give me some guidance

```
# array of dependencies
array=("convert" "ffmpeg");
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    command -v $i >/dev/null 2>&1 || { 
        echo >&2 "$i required"; 
        exit 1; 
    }
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) to make sure the code executes in bash and not the default shell. At the start of the script there should be the line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This is because your array syntax is only supported in Bash, not in more basic shells which are often used by default for performance reasons.

Comment: Note that this is a very common problem; such questions should be closed as duplicates rather than answered, as described in the "Answer Well-Asked Questions" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer